# jQuery making only one div appear at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make divs appear and disappear by clicking on their thumbnails, but I can't figure out how to make them disappear after I make another one appear (the room variable changes its value), they just get placed after each other. The goal is to have only one div appeared at a time.

Here's my last try:

```
 jQuery('.thumbs a').click(function () {
        var room = "#room" + $(this).data('slide');
        $(document).trigger('data-changed');
    });
        $(document).on('data-changed', function() {
        $(room).toggleSlide('fast');
        });
```

Sorry if its hard to understand.

Comment: can you send the html

Comment: `room` isn't defined in the data-changed handler.

Comment: Here's the actual html, i removed the unnecesary parts. http://pastebin.com/S8XqwCFq

Comment: Check console for errors...

Comment: I know that example is a bad one. I'm trying to find another way to make it work. But I have no idea how to make the div disappear before I make another one appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS:

```
#wrapper div{
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery('.thumbs a').click(function () {
      room = "#room" + $(this).data('slide');
    $(room).slideToggle('fast');

    $('#wrapper').children().not(room).slideUp('fast');

    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ffoa3pno/1/